# Directory import is not supported resolving ES modules when trying import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Tags: node.js, import, rxjs

I'm getting the following error when trying to import the map operator. 
**Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import is not supported resolving ES modules imported from**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Node version: **v14.15.0**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that ES6 modules are not yet supported 
To be able to import the **map** module I needed to use internals as follow:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map.js';
```

Hope this might help someone.

Comment: generic solution: append `/index.js`